# Is there any way to add the social medial buttons in a field?

Tags: 7, entities

I have made the field using field collection which is collection of 7 fields and the 8th field I would like to add as strip of social media buttons (like easy social module).

So when the entire content is displayed, below each set of field collections the social media button appears.

I searched and found that all social modules can be attached to content type which adds at the top of content or bottom. But is there a way where it can be added in-between the text or using CKeditor, the above issue can be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Link icon](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkicon) module.

> The Link icon module is a simple link field formatter to create icon
>   classes based on a predefined set of link titles.

Or the [Social field](https://www.drupal.org/project/socialfield) module

> The Social field module provides a field that allows you to collect
>   links to social network profiles like facebook, twitter, googleplus,
>   linkedin, etc. Links are shown as icons. Social field links are
>   validated according to the patterns inserted in the module
>   configuration.

Comment: Hi, thank for the answer. I checked both modules and can be used as field and I guess it provides icon and link to the social site or social url, so when person clicks it, he reached to the standard login site i.e. tweeter.com/ or the link tweeter.com/yoursitepage/. I guess it does not work like Easy Social or ShareThis module, which provides the sharing of that content-url on the social media. Does this modules can do that?  If I have not explicitly explained about sharing feature sorry for that, I am looking for sharing of content url on social media.  Thanks for answer though.

Comment: @codenext If this is the real problem, I think that you must edit your question, maybe this was the cause of the downvote (I'm not the downvoter) I don't know if the modules have this feature, but you can test the functionality

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will start a new question and will specify that features and conditions. Thanks